# バグを一緒に直しましょう

Tags: 討議

プログラマーの皆さんもよく存知の通りバグ修正とは難しいものです。当サイトのバグは日本語のため、日本語が話せない開発者にとっては修正がより難しくなります。いち早く直せるように、バグのワークフローを改善する予定です。下記の項目についてご協力のほど宜しくお願いします。

1. スクリーンショットの添付
2. 翻訳支援
3. 解決に向けて

#### スクリーンショットの添付

バグを再現させるのが難しい為できるだけスクリーンショットを添付してください。スクリーンショットがあれば再現そして解決が楽になります。

#### 翻訳支援

各バグの下に、日本語が読めない当社の開発者のために英語のサマリーを追加させていただきます。翻訳の支援をいただけたら幸いです（もちろん強制ではありません）。

#### 解決に向けて

バグについて開発者が英語でお返事することがあります。その回答は当社側が翻訳しますが、追加情報等のリクエストがあればご協力のほど宜しくお願いします。

優先度の高いバグがある場合、この投稿のコメントでどうぞお知らせください。開発者の優先順位を一部調整することができます。

そして、今から[バグリスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%E3%83%90%E3%82%B0%5D+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-planned%5D+-%5Bstatus-deferred%5D+-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D+-%5Bstatus-norepro%5D+-%5Bstatus-review%5D+-%5Bstatus-reproduced%5D+closed%3Ano)の翻訳作業を開始します！

Comment: ワークフローを改善するというのは開発者側の話でしょうか。ユーザーはこれまで通りメタで報告すればいいのですよね？

Comment: @unarist そうですね。できるだけスクリーンショットを添付してくれたら幸甚ですが、今のままでも問題無いです。

Comment: @jmac バグリストを見ていたのですが、重複 (closed) があると見づらかったので、リンクを更新してみました。

Comment: @YukiInoue ありがとうございます！